# Ошибка при добавлении и удалении строк в JList

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

Как добавить массив в `JList`? Так можно построчно или через цикл

```
DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
jList1.setModel(dlm);
dlm.addElement("1234");
```

А можно сразу массив?

Строки добавляются и появляется второй вопрос, как удалить их из списка?
Пробую так:

```
DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
jList1.setModel(dlm);
int del = jList1.getSelectedIndex();
if(del == -1)System.out.println("-1");
else System.out.println(del);
```

Всегда возвращается -1, соответственно использовать `dlm.remove();` не получится.
Но даже если указать конкретно `dlm.remove(4)`, то вылетает с ошибкой выхода за границу массива, хотя Лист заполнен. Попробовал следующее:

```
private void jList1ValueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt)
{
    int idx = jList1.getSelectedIndex();
    if(idx != -1) { System.out.println("Selected:" + Arr[idx]); }
    else System.out.println("Selected list");
}
```

Результат получается ещё интереснее.
Он задвоеный. Т.к клацаешь на листбоксе этом, и выводит два раза выбранную строку. Почему, непонятно.

В общем прошу пример удаления строк.

#### UPDATE

По поводу добавления. Сделал свой класс:

```
class AddStringToList
{
 JList obj;

AddStringToList(JList obj,String Array[])
{
    this.obj = obj;

     obj.setModel(new AbstractListModel() {
        String strings[] = Array;
        @Override
        public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
        @Override
        public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
    });


}
}
```

В принципе так устроит. По поводу удаления.  Я не могу объявить  JList, т.к он уже объявлен и изменить тоже не могу НетБинс не дает менять. Если прямо объявлю, то перекрою уже созданный. В этом то как раз и проблема.

```
 private void RemoveStringBtn_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                              

    try
    {
      DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
      jList1.setModel(dlm); 

      int selected = jList1.getSelectedIndex();
        if ( selected != -1 ) {
            dlm.remove( selected );
        }           

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       System.out.println("Error:" + e); 
     }



}
```

И получаю Error null. И очищается весь список.
Пробую так:

```
 private void jList1ValueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) 
{     
   if(!evt.getValueIsAdjusting())
    {
       if(jList1.getSelectedIndex() != -1)
        {    
         DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
         jList1.setModel(dlm); 
         dlm.remove(jList1.getSelectedIndex());
        } 
       else System.out.println("-1");
    }
 }
```

Получаю -1 и соответственно выход за границы массива. Но строки то в Листе то есть. Почему выход?

> > Начните с того, что объявите модель списка полем класса формы, или где там у вас список:

```
private javax.swing.DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
```

Вот в этом то и закавыка. Не дает редактировать поля где среда вставляет код.
Везде указано // Variables declaration - do not modify . И не дает ничего изменить

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, минимальный компилируемый код. Это означает, что код должен компилироваться и в нём не должно быть лишних элементов.

Comment: А элементов сколько в списке? `dlm.remove(0)` тоже ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: @Suvitruf, да выдает ошибку выхода за массив.

Comment: Уже руки опускаются. Может кто нить дать пример в НетБинс с одним листбоксом и кнопкой с кодом удаления? Или выслать на почту.

Answer (score 1):

> Как добавить массив в JList? Так можно построчно или через цикл

`DefaultListModel` позволяет добавлять только по одному элементу. Можно сделать свой класс, с хранением данных в `ArrayList` например, унаследовав от `AbstractListModel` и добавить методы работы по вкусу (с вызовами `fireXXXX`, чтобы сообщать `JList` об изменениях).

> Строки добавляются и появляется второй вопрос, как удалить их из списка? Пробую так:

Если прямо так пробуете, то, во-первых `new DefaultListModel()` создает пустую модель, во-вторых установка модели сбрасывает выбор элементов. Можете написать:

```
JList<String> jList1 = new JList<String>();

DefaultListModel<String> dlm = new DefaultListModel<>();
jList1.setModel( dlm );

dlm.addElement("1234");
dlm.addElement("1235");
dlm.addElement("1236");
dlm.addElement("1237");

jList1.setSelectedIndex( 2 );
System.out.println( jList1.getSelectedIndex() );
```

Будет выбрана третья сверху строка, в консоль выведет `2` (нумерация строк с 0)

> Результат получается ещё интереснее. Он задвоеный. Т.к клацаешь на
>   листбоксе этом, и выводит два раза выбранную строку. Почему,
>   непонятно.

Так работает [`ListSelectionModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#setValueIsAdjusting%28boolean%29). В событии есть свойство `ValueIsAdjusting`, которое указывает, продолжаются еще изменения в выборе, или нет. Можете зажать мышь и посмотреть вывод:

```
jList1.addListSelectionListener( new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        System.out.println( "is adjusting? " + e.getValueIsAdjusting() );
    }
});
```

Пока не отпустите, на каждую смену выделения будет приходить по одному сообщению с `true`, а в конце одно с `false`.

Пример с удалением:

```
public class JListExample {

    public static void createUi() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JList example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        JPanel content = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );

        JList<String> jList1 = new JList<String>();

        DefaultListModel<String> dlm = new DefaultListModel<>();
        jList1.setModel( dlm );

        dlm.addElement("1234");
        dlm.addElement("1235");
        dlm.addElement("1236");
        dlm.addElement("1237");

        content.add( jList1, BorderLayout.CENTER );

        JButton button = new JButton( "delete!" );
        button.setEnabled( false );

        jList1.addListSelectionListener( event -> {
            if ( !event.getValueIsAdjusting() ) {
                // getSelectedIndex возвращает индекс самой верхней выбранной строки
                button.setEnabled( jList1.getSelectedIndex() != -1 );
            }
        });

        button.addActionListener( event -> {
            int selected = jList1.getSelectedIndex();
            if ( selected != -1 ) {
                dlm.remove( selected );
            }           
        });

        content.add( button, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

        frame.setContentPane( content );
        frame.setSize( 640, 480 );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater( JListExample::createUi );
    }
}
```

Обновление:

Ок, у вас редактор форм от NetBeans - это звучит, как приговор.

Начните с того, что объявите модель списка полем класса формы, или где там у вас список:

```
private javax.swing.DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
```

Теперь установите эту модель вашему списку либо через редактор свойства `model` (тип "Изменяемый код", значение "model"), либо прописав в конструкторе после `initComponents` прямо так:

```
public NewJFrame() {
    initComponents();
    jList1.setModel(model);
}
```

Все. Дальше, когда вам понадобится что-то от модели - используйте `model`.

То, что делаете вы - просто безумно:

```
// данные, отображаемые JList хранятся в модели
if(jList1.getSelectedIndex() != -1)
{   
    // вы создали новую ПУСТУЮ модель
    DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel();
    // вы назначили новую пустую модель JList-у
    jList1.setModel(dlm); // пуф, все содержимое пропадает
    // вы удаляете из новой ПУСТОЙ модели элемент, которого там нет
    dlm.remove(jList1.getSelectedIndex()); // бабах, вылетает ArrayIndexOutOfBounds
}
```

Вы могли бы сделать:

```
// взять у JList текущую модель, привести ее к типу DefaultListModel
DefaultListModel dlm = (DefaultListModel)jList1.getModel()
```

но NetBeans по-умолчанию устанавливает в модель анонимный класс от `AbstractListModel`, и вы получите `ClassCastException`.